# Getting error messages while connecting to snowflake database though ODBC

Tags: php, odbc, unixodbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Ubuntu, I am trying to connect php to snowflake using ODBC driver, I have added driver information in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`. Here is the driver information, that I am using

```
[ODBC Drivers]
SnowflakeDSIIDriver=Installed

[SnowflakeDSIIDriver]
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYY
Description=Snowflake DSII
Driver=path-to-"libSnowflake.so"
DriverODBCVer=03.52
SQLLevel=1
ErrorMessagesPath=path-to-folder-which-has-error-message-xml-files
```

I am getting error two erros

The error 1 : `SFRestRequestFailed could not be found in the en-US locale. Check that /en-US/SFMessages.xml exists`.

The error 2 : `REST request to the Snowflake is failing(I got this error by checking corresponding message attached to 'SFRestRequestFailed' in SFMessages.xml)`.

But I am able to connect Snowflake and fetch data using same access details in windows.

Kindly share your ideas to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

ErrorMessagePath is a snowflake configuration. If you use the snowflake odbc package for linux, you will find unixodbc.snowflake.ini or iodbc.snowflake.ini which you can use accordingly depending on which driver manager you are using. ErrorMessagePath should be set in unixodbc.snowflake.ini or iodbc.snowflake.ini and your SIMBAINI env var should be set to point to one of these files.